# Display docx or ppt in browser with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docx

I'm currently working on a intranet webapp for a company.
I've created it so the administrators of the site are able to upload files 
(.docx, .pdf, .xlsx, .ppt etc)
 up to the webapp, to provide easier access 
to documents for the employees.
 It works very well, however my client wasn't
too fond of having to download the files,
 and wanted it to pop up in the browser, 
or open up the file-spesific program instead of download.

I was playing with some ideas:
1. Somehow parse the files to JSON at upload, and then show the content in browser with html.
2. Generate a pdf from the uploaded file (which automatically launches in the browser).
3. Somehow use a previewer to show the filecontent in the browser
4. Clients computer launches the uploaded file automatically on download, however I think this is a bit more tricky...

What would be the best and most time-efficient way to go about this?

Comment: It's unreliable for any but Microsoft's solutions that can use Office formats' specifications (if they exist, which I sincerely hope, jk). The format is really tricky and converting to PDF (or anything else really) is a major risk of data/formatting loss. Given a choice of having to download files or viewing corrupted documents without downloading, I'd choose the former. PDFs would essentially make documents read-only anyway.

Comment: `.docx` and `.xlsx` are open ISO standards (ISO Office OpenXML).

Comment: @JörgWMittag good to know that my info is a bit outdated! Rendering differences are still there though, so at present that makes the situation better, but not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like what you actually want/need is a javascript document viewer (only) such as http://viewerjs.org/.

Comment: This may actually be what I need. I|m gonna check it out and play around with it for a bit to see if it suits my needs. Much appreciated!

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois pleasure to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it turns out to fit your use case :)